# Bluemix_Access to File storage

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I have bluemix account(trial version) and I have configured MobileFirst Foundation on it.

> **So my question is,**
>
> Like Amazon cloud(AWS), Is Bluemix(licensed copy) also provides access
>   to file Storage? creadentials for the server (Win/linux)?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking if Bluemix offers any type of file storage service? Like object storage, for example? You should elaborate on your question a bit more.

Comment: Ok. There are two scenarios - **1.** I will deploy Adapter and register apps on MobileFirst Foundation. For this adapter, I have to place one config file at some location which has some config data. So what is the option/way to place this  config file at server? and  **2.** How log analysis can be done?? On Mobilefirst console we can only check console operation related logs, but how I can check logs of Adapter(api calls related logs), as my adapter will act as middleware here

Comment: Hi, any reply on above questions please. I **found the solution for first** question i.e placing config file but can anyone help me, **where I will find adapter logs**, i.e. the interaction logs between app - adapter - backend server. _italic_e.g for debugging purpose, if I have added some logs (logger) in my adapter code then in which (or where) log I will found the logs which i have placed in the code?_italic_